# Amcharts.js dataProvider not recognizing List of Objects

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to use the [amchart](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/) 
library to display charts on a website using HTML. I have gone through the tutorial found [here](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/your-first-chart-with-amcharts/). My code is mostly copy pasted from the tutorial, and if I use their list of Objects, it will display, but if I use mine, it doesn't show up. I build my list of objects the following way:

```
    var coordList = [];

    function coord(x,y) {
        this.x_coord = x;
        this.y_coord = y;
    }

    var newCoord = new coord(line[0],y_value);
    coordList.push(newCoord);
```

I have some "for" loop that creates new objects to be pushed inside the list. It will display the chart if coordList is written this way directly:

```
    coordList = [{"x_coord":"Monday","y_coord":4}];
```

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong with my list of objects created through a constructor?

EDIT: Ok, After testing, it seems like I simply don't understand exactly how JS works.

```
var coordList = []; // list of coordinates {x,y}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./test.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        processData(data);
        console.log(coordList);
        displayChart();
        console.log("hello");
    }
    });
});
```

Above, is the main part of the code. Before, the displayChart() was outside of the doc ready part, meaning it would immediately display the chart with no data, since the data had not yet been processed (Correct me if I am wrong?). I have since put it inside the doc ready part. Hopefully, when the document is ready, the data is processed, and will display the chart. However it still doesn't.

This is what displayChart() looks like:

```
    function displayChart() {

        //coordList = [{"x_coord":"Monday","y_coord":4}];
        console.log(coordList);

                var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                chart.dataProvider = coordList;
                chart.categoryField = "x_coord";    

                console.log("hello2");

                var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph.valueField = "y_coord";
                graph.type = "column";
                chart.addGraph(graph);

                chart.write('chartdiv');
    }
```

EDIT #2: I FIGURED IT OUT, THE ENTIRE SCRIPT HAD TO BE INSIDE THE AMCHART READY! This can be closed, I don't know if I can do it myself?